# print - passing a variable as value inside a nested {}

Tags: python, printing

I would like to pass the variable startsLen as value to be printed in a nested {} this is my code that

```
m = {
    'TEST 11' : 1,
    'TEST 22' : 1,
    'TEST 33': 1,
    'TEST 44': 1,
    'TEST 55' : 1
}
startsLen = 3

for i in m:
    t = 0
    a = (len(i))
    b = (len(str(m[i])))
    t = a+b
    if t > startsLen:
        startsLen += t


table = ''
for row in m:
    table += ("{: <22} {}".format(row, m[row]))
    table +='\n'

print (table)
```

this will print

```
TEST 11                1
TEST 22                1
TEST 33                1
TEST 44                1
TEST 55                1
```

I need to do something like :

```
table += ("{: < {}} {}".format(startsLen, row, m[row]))
```

Any advise please

Comment: How is your desired output look like?

Comment: the output should be the same